# How can I apply a linear transformation on sparse matrix in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

In PyTorch, we have `nn.linear` that applies a linear transformation to the incoming data:

```
y = WA+b
```

In this formula, `W` and `b` are our learnable parameters and `A` is my input data matrix. The matrix 'A' for my case is too large for RAM to complete loading, so I use it sparsely. Is it possible to perform such an operation on sparse matrices using PyTorch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with PyTorch using [sparse matrix multiply](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html). In your case, I think you want something like:

```
>> i = [[0, 1, 1],
     [2, 0, 2]]
>> v =  [3, 4, 5]
>> A = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(i, v, (2, 3))
>> A.to_dense()
tensor([[0, 0, 3],
    [4, 0, 5]])
# compute W@A by computing ((A.T)@(W.T)).T because...
# at time of writing, the sparse matrix must be first in the matmul
>> (A.t() @ W.t()).t()
```